# How can I change a v-for single item while looping in vuejs 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to accomplish the following:

```js
<tr v-for="item in items" :key='item'>
 <td v-for="field in fields" :key='field'>
        {{ item[field.toLowerCase()] }}
 </td>
</tr>
```

As you may notice, my `field` variable is the key for each `item` element however this is coming back as `Name` or  `ID` and I cannot use them that way. I don't want to have `item[field.toLowerCase()]` as I would like to have it in a neater way and only use `item[keyField]` where `keyField` is a modification of `field`.

Is it possible to do something like that in VueJS 3? I tried the following:

```js
<tr v-for="item in items" :key='item'>
 <td v-for="field.toLowerCase() as keyField in fields" :key='field'>
        {{ item[keyField] }}
 </td>
</tr>
```

But it didn't work .

Comment: I did not see any drawback in using `item[field.toLowerCase()]`. Is there any specific reason you want to format the string seperately instead of inline ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to achieve it the way you want.

But you could use a `function`/`computed property` to lowercase your fields.

Check [Displaying Filtered/Sorted Results](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#array-change-detection)

You can also apply `toLowerCase()` to your array directly using `map`

```
fields.map((f) => f.toLowerCase())
```

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const App = { 
  setup() {
    const fields = ref(['My Field 1', 'My Field 2']);
    return { fields }
  }
  
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
   <div v-for="keyField in fields.map((f) => f.toLowerCase())" :key='keyField'>
         keyField:{{ keyField }}
   </div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! It does work. I ended up looping the array at first and then sending the using the variable at my template since that v-for is inside another v-for ( the are table headers) and I don't want to loop them every time.